# Pyramid star pattern programs in C with recursion

Tags: c

How do I write a pyramid of stars in .txt file using a recursive function in C?
Example, for an triangle pyramid star pattern of 5 rows program's output should be:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

I did the non-recursive:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i, space, rows, star = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    //printing one row in every iteration
    for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
        /* Printing spaces */
        for(space = 1; space <= rows - i; space++){
           printf(" ");
        }
        //Printing stars
        while(star != (2 * i - 1)){
            printf("*");
            star++;
        }
        star = 0;
        //move to next row
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Cannot figure out recursion excatly.

```
void print_pattern(int spaces, int stars){
    static int spaces = 4, stars = 1, number_of_lines = 5;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i <= spaces; i++)
        printf(" ");                //print spaces
    for(j = 1; j <= stars; j++)
        printf("*");                //print stars
    if(number_of_lines > 0){
        number_of_lines -= 1;
        //call recursively if all lines are not printed
        print_pattern(spaces - 1, stars + 1);   
    }
}
```

Comment: think about the problem, and try to solve it, then post where you are stuck!!

Comment: You might try writing a function which takes the base width, in characters, and the current width in characters. Figure out how to center the current width in the base width and print that number of asterisks. Then, if the current width isn't equal to the base width, call the function recursively, passing in the base width and the current width plus two. Have fun.

Comment: 1) `void function(num);` --> `function(num);`, `void funk(num);` --> `function(num);`,  `dat ` --> `f`

Comment: 2) `f = fopen("pyramid.txt", "w");` Do not open the file every function call, the contents of the previous file will be lost depending on `"w"` mode.

Comment: I call fopen in definition of main function.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/mOV5GD)

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function can be written the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. All you need to do is to supply a file name, open the file and pass the pointer to the file in the function. In the demonstrative program there is used `stdin` as the function argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void pyramid( FILE *f, unsigned int n )
{
    static int width = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        ++width;
        pyramid( f, n - 1 );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++ )
        {
            fprintf( f, "%*c", i == 0 ? width : 1, '*' );
        }

        fputc( '\n', f );

        --width;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        pyramid( stdout, n );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

   *
  ***
 *****
*******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

  *
 ***
*****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

 *
***

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```